# Empires and the net criterion

Tags: ct.category-theory, lo.logic, monoidal-categories, proof-theory, linear-logic

Currently, I am struggling to understand the proof of Proposition 2.5 on page 250 (page 22 in the document) of the paper [*Natural deduction and coherence for weakly distributive categories*](https://www.math.mcgill.ca/rags/nets/nets.pdf) by Blute, Cockett, Seely and Trimble:

> A (non-planar) $(\oplus,\otimes)$-circuit with components $C$ is sequential if and only if it satisfies the net criterion.

Up to the paragraph starting with „Assume that all circuits satisfying the net criterion, but not the proposition, sequentialize to a sequent box circuit […]“ I understand the proof, I think.
Then confusion sets in:

1. The authors introduce the term *(switching) empire*:

> When we disconnect its nonswitching wire, the subcircuit of those components still connected to it, no matter how the switches are set, is the *(switching) empire* of that link (relative to the given disconnection).

I am not sure, I understand their definition. Consider each proof circuit $P$ as a graph $GP$ by replacing each link by a node. Let $c$ be a switching link in $P$. Denote the connected component (of the graph one obtains by deleting the non-switching edge of the node corresponding to $c$ in $GP$) that contains the node corresponding to $c$ by $C$. Is the (switching) empire of $c$ simply the proof circuit one obtains by translating $C$ back into a proof circuit (if necessary by „extending“ wires)?
For instance, in the following image is the proof circuit marked in blue the empire of the switchable link $c$?

[image]

2. The authors state that Proposition 2.5 is wrong for planar circuits. They give the following counterexample:

[image]

One easily verifies that this proof circuit satisfies the net criterion. According to Proposition 2.5 therefore it is sequential as a non-planar circuit. I was able to sequentialize it using the non-planar cut-rule. Why is this proof circuit not sequentializable as a planar proof circuit?